# Static block in between products in grid mode

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, product-view, grid-layout

I want to place a static block in between the product list of the category 'shoes' (ID 20).

The static block is a simple banner for test:
[image]

I want it in the second row, after the first two products of this row:
[image]

I have already tried to use the display mode setting for the category in the backend:
[image]

But when I do this, the static block is displayed above the grid, not inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write below code in your list.phtml file

```
<?php echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/category_view')->getCmsBlockHtml(); ?>
```

Try and let me know if its not working

Comment: It works, and very well. Also I am wondering, is there also another way to do this? Without using the list.phtml file? Just curious

Comment: You can use this code any where just Need to set extra method after this code`->setCategory($category_object);`